# Struggling using react-redux hooks with state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Hello fellow developers,

I'm creating a little app in react native, and i'm using react-redux to store and manage my datas.  I've got an events.js reducer registered in my store, using 'events/load' dispatch action to set the initialState in my App.js. It looks like that :

```
import { auth, firestore } from '../lib/firebase'

const initialState = {
  events: [],
  userEvents: []
}

export default async function eventsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'events/load': {
      const userId = auth.currentUser.uid
      const eventsData = []
      const userEventsData = []
      // starts with other events
      const queryEvents = await firestore.collection("events").where("userId", "!=", userId).get()
      if (queryEvents) {
        queryEvents.forEach(ev => {
          eventsData.push(Object.assign({}, { id: ev.id }, ev.data()))
        })
      }
      // user events
      const userEvents = await firestore.collection("events").where("userId", "==", userId).get()
      if (userEvents) {
        userEvents.forEach(ev => {
          userEventsData.push(Object.assign({}, { id: ev.id }, ev.data()))
        })
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        events: eventsData,
        userEvents: userEventsData
      }
    }
    case 'events/set': {
      // Set the classics events
      return {
        ...state,
        events: action.payload
      }
    }
    case 'userEvents/set': {
      // Set the userEvents
      return {
        ...state,
        userEvents: action.payload
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now, I have a screen, using SectionList from react native, and I want to display there all the userEvents from my store, previously loaded. The problem is that my useSelector hook only return Promise when i try to get events. If i try to get events.userEvents, it's undefined.
Here what it look like :

```
const Manage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
  const eventsSelector = useSelector((state) => state.events)
  
  // use effect one time
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadDatas() {
      console.log('events selected', eventsSelector) // what i've got in my events ?

      // get the datas for coming events
      const storedEventsIds = []
      const comingEvents = []
      const passedEvents = []

      if (eventsSelector !== null) {
        eventsSelector.userEvents.forEach(event => { // <= THIS IS NOT WORKING - error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

          // compare dates to know if it's a coming or passed event
          const dateTimeStart = new Date(`${event.dateStart} ${event.timeStart}`)
          const dateTimeEnd = new Date(`${event.dateEnd} ${event.timeEnd}`)
          const dateNow = new Date()
    
          if (!(doc.id in storedEventsIds)) {
            if (compareAsc(dateTimeStart, dateNow) >= 0 ||
            (compareAsc(dateTimeStart, dateNow) < 0 && compareAsc(dateTimeEnd, dateNow) >= 0)) {
              comingEvents.push(Object.assign({}, event, {id: doc.id, passed: false}))
              storedEventsIds.push(doc.id)
            } else {
              passedEvents.push(Object.assign({}, event, {id: doc.id, passed: true}))
              storedEventsIds.push(doc.id)
            }
          }
        })
      }
  
      // set events
      setEvents([{
        title: "Événements à venir",
        data: comingEvents
      }, {
        title: "Événéments passés",
        data: passedEvents
      }]);
      setLoading(false)
  
    };
    loadDatas()
  }, [])
  
  // ... omitted manage component code - basically only html
}
```

When i console log my eventsSelector this is what i've got, so you can see that I have some userEvents. But it's a Promise and i don't really know why...

```
events selected Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 1,
  "_W": Object {
    "_U": 0,
    "_V": 1,
    "_W": Object {
      "events": Array [],
      "userEvents": Array [],
    },
    "_X": null,
    "events": Array [],
    "userEvents": Array [
      Object {
        "coverImage": null,
        "dateEnd": "04/02/2022",
        "dateStart": "04/11/2021",
        "description": "Hbzbwkks
Sjjdjdjdjd
Wjdkkdieizhdbf
Sjjdjdjdjd",
        "id": "ewPrFzAqQmusKrsqQnSP",
        "maxLimit": null,
        "online": true,
        "openPrice": false,
        "place": null,
        "price": 50,
        "secretPlace": false,
        "timeEnd": "17:25",
        "timeStart": "17:25",
        "title": "Mon super event",
        "userId": "pPL2g7bWDYZDzUGtlGCSyLOQ3WK2",
        "website": "https://bloodbee.space",
      },
      Object {
        "dateEnd": "05/10/2021",
        "dateStart": "04/10/2021",
        "description": "La teuf de l'année - 24h de folie ouais :)",
        "id": "gSlmysO0KffkjGKyP9fR",
        "maxLimit": 3000,
        "online": false,
        "openPrice": false,
        "place": "Puy du pariou",
        "price": 30,
        "secretPlace": true,
        "timeEnd": "23:00",
        "timeStart": "23:00",
        "title": "Rave party de l'année",
        "userId": "pPL2g7bWDYZDzUGtlGCSyLOQ3WK2",
        "website": null,
      },
    ],
  },
  "_X": null,
}
```

How can I fix this ? Do you have any improvment suggestions ?

Thank you for your help :)

Edit :
Some code about my App.js

```
const AppWrapped = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  const loadApp = async () => {
    // Manage auth
    await auth.onAuthStateChanged( async (user) => {
      if (user) {        
        // Log the user
        await dispatch({ type: 'users/set', payload: user })
        
        // dispatch to get events
        await dispatch({ type: 'events/load' })

        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        setSignedIn(true)
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        await dispatch({ type: 'users/set', payload: null })
        setSignedIn(false)
      }
    })
  }

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
          startAsync={loadApp}
          onFinish={() => setAppIsReady(true)}
          onError={console.warn}
          autoHideSplash={true}
        />
    )
  } else {
    // omitted html - when the app is ready - no more splashscreen
  }
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppWrapped />
      </PaperProvider>
    </StoreProvider>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

did you dispatch the events/load action ?

```
/// src/redux/events/eventActions.js

import store from '../store'

function loadEvents() {
  return {
    type: 'events/load'
  }
}

store.dispatch(loadEvents())
```

A good practice is to create a const for every action like this :

```
/// src/redux/events/eventTypes.js

const LOAD_EVENTS = 'events/load';
```

```
/// src/redux/events/eventActions.js

import store from '../store'
import { LOAD_EVENTS } from './eventTypes.js'

function loadEvents() {
  return {
    type: LOAD_EVENTS
  }
}

store.dispatch(loadEvents())
```

```
/// src/redux/events/eventReducer.js

import { LOAD_EVENTS } from './eventTypes.js'

const initialState = {
  events: [],
  ...
}

export default async function eventsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_EVENTS: {
      
      ... Some code

      return {
        ...state,
        events: eventsData,
        userEvents: userEventsData
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as an addition: Generally, the practice of using string type constants is outdated and not recommended any more. Modern Redux handles string types internally as an implementation detail and you don't have to write them any more at all. For a quick overview I'd recommend reading https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux and for a longer tutorial I'd recommend the full official Redux "essentials" tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
To respond, yes I dispatched my events/load action, in my App.js, as said before in my question. I've got some events in my state (see my console log).
Then, about the documentation you provided, there are some good fundamentals, but it's all about redux toolkit, which i'm not using.
I've updated my question with some of my App.js code.

Comment: Update : It looks like right now it's really hard to use only react-redux without the RTK. Shame, as it put more logical complex code. Anyway, I managed do to what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks @phry, I didn't notice that. I will apply it to my future projects.

Comment: @MathieuDfr Redux Toolkit is the official recommendation for *any Redux code* you write since 2019. It essentially *is* Redux at this point.
If you don't use it, yes, you will face all issues people had before 2019 and why the Redux Toolkit was created.